# Set tr background color dynamically group by field partial view for mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop

I have a dynamic table and i want to change the row background color to different for group by field1 and field2.
i did code like below but it can't work.

```
var count = 0;
var color = new string[] { " odd", " even" };
var val1 = "";
var val2 = "";
foreach (var val in Model.listofFields)
{
    if (val1 == "" && val2== "")
    {
        val1 = val.field1;
        val2 = val.field2;
    }
    if (val1 == val.field1 && val2 == val.field2)
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    else if ((val1 != val.field1 && val2 != val.field2))
    {
        count = 1;
        val1 = val.field1;
        val2 = val.field2;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 1;
        val1 = "";
        val2 = "";
    }
    <tr class="@color[count]">
    <td>@val.field1</td>
    <td>@val.field2</td>
    <td>@val.field3</td>
    <td>@val.field4</td>
    <td>@val.field5</td>
    <td>@val.field5</td>
</tr>
}
```

also attached file for sample [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set value in one comparision variable this will help you to make color for group.

```
var val1 = "";
string color = "odd";
foreach (var val in Model.listofFields)
{
    if (val1 != (val.field1 + val.field2))
    {
        color = color == "odd" ?  "even" : "odd" ;
        val1 = (val.field1 + val.field2);
    }
    
    <tr class="@color">
    <td>@val.field1</td>
    <td>@val.field2</td>
    <td>@val.field3</td>
    <td>@val.field4</td>
    <td>@val.field5</td>
    <td>@val.field5</td>
</tr>
}
```